# how to dynamically change a image in AEM forms workflow step

Tags: adobe, aem, jcr

I need to load a image for jcr node in a form for assigned step workflow task.
The image was uploaded in previous step is in payload.

**/var/fd/dashboard/payload/server0/2018-11-27/3G76W5ICECE6PISS6ADU4IH24M_6/Attach/fileupload/file.jpg**

I prefilled text's fields with XmlData  but I can't do it with an image. What is the correct form to prefill this image component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of tests, and some help by Adobe forum guys, I resolved this issue.

The solution is provide a css class name to the the image component using the properties editor (like imgCNH), and, use this class name to set its src attribute using jquery.

But, it's a little more. AEM Forms give a name setted to a DIV tag, not the IMG tag.  By that, to try change the src for imgCNH failed.

The trick is access the IMG tag below named DIV. I used this:

**CSS Class attribute**:  imgCNH  (give a name to field)

**jquery code**: $("*.imgCNH, img*").attr("src","/content/dam/foxfly/jean CNH.jpg");

**Explanation**:

.imgCNH - Select DIV named in by CSS Class atribute

, img - Selet tag IMG below the DV

I hope this help you.